# Which pattern should I use to run some action based on command name?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Prerequisites:

```
String command = "x";
Data data = request.get();

interface Action {
    Response process(Data data);
}

class ActionX implements Action {
    public Response process(Data data) {}
}

class Service {
    public execute(Action action) {
        action.process();
    }
}
```

I dont't understand how to register my actions. The following options are unacceptable:

```
// bad because too verbose
case "x":
    action = new ActionX();

and

// bad because package name is a constant string      
action = Class.forName("some.package.name.Action" + command.toUpperCase());
```

I guess I might try to use Java annotations to solve my problem. Something like this:

```
@Action(command = "x")
class ActionX implements Action {}

// scan whole classpath etc ...
```

But maybe I just need to use another pattern....

Comment: You have to validate that the command is a correct input you can work with. So the switch is a good solution. Why you do not want to use it?

Comment: @Blobonat Because conditional operator which contains many options (i need > 100) looks ugly. Such statements will be hard to read, hard to test and hard to maintain. I think this is a code smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*According to me*, [Factory design pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) (or *Abstract factory design pattern*) is *suitable* in this case. *I might be wrong.*

- Annotation based way is *overkill* for this situation
- Switch case is not verbose at all.

You can try following way with factory pattern,

```
enum Command {
    X("x");

    private String commandString;

    Command(String commandString) {
        this.commandString = commandString;
    }

    public String getCommandString() {
        return commandString;
    }
}

interface Action {
    void process();
}

class ActionX implements Action {

    @Override
    public void process() {
        System.out.println("Processing..");
    }
}

class ActionFactory {
    public Action getAction(Command command) {
        // Check command and return action
        // Switch is the best suitable here
        return action;
    }
}
```

*Thinking about the situation where you have lots of commands and so many actions.... !?* In that case, you must look in to your design first and some sort of more *analysis* can be done instead of deciding about design patterns first.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the Class.forName(""). I would go for the switch case but maybe change the command representation to an enum instead of a String.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map:

```
Map<String, Action> map = ...;

map.put("x", new ActionX());

Response response = map.get("x").process(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the command name is an inherent part of the command (as opposed to being configured externally). If that's the case, *model it that way*:

```
interface Action {
    String name();
    Response process(Data data);
}
```

Then you can simply create a `Map<String,Action>` that uses each action's name as the key.

If you want to make command classes discoverable instead of hard-coding them and you're not using an existing scanner like Spring, you should use the [Service Provider Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html).

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about SPI.